# Update ACF fields inside layout via WP API

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to update a custom field via the WordPress API. The custom field is within an Advanced Custom Fields repeating layout and I cannot figure out how to update it.

I have authentication set up and can update a post status, but I'm not having any luck in updating the ACF data.

Using Postman : Page status can be updated with `http://localhost:9000/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/4564/?status=public`. Is there a similar value which can be used to update the ACF field or a way to update by passing JSON instead?

```
{
    "id": 4564,
     ...
    "acf": {
        "insert_to_head": "",
        "insert_to_foot": "",
        "Layout": [
            {
                "acf_fc_layout": "cert_challenge_pin",
                "challenge_pin": "0527881"
            }]
}
```

The ACF to REST API plugin is in use and fields can be viewed via the API but not updated.

Having exhausted search and documentation, any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: screenshot from postman]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found from [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-update-acfs-using-json/) that you should use the key `fields` instead of `acf`. In addition, I had to send a `Content-type: application/json` header to get it working.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. Replacing `acf` with `fields` does indeed allow passing JSON such as 
```{ 
 "fields": {
  "show_banner": true
 }
}```

However I'm unable to extend this to the fields nested within layout. For example:

```{ 
 "fields": {
  "show_banner": true,
  "layout": {
   "challenge_pin": "1626014"
  }
 }
}```

Comment: The format needed was:

```{ 
 "fields": {
  "Layout": [{
                "acf_fc_layout": "certification_challenge_pin",
                "challenge_pin": "new challenge pin"
            }]
 }
}```

Thank you for your help.