# I can't update a Wordpress ACF field assigned to a user from the restapi via a ReactJs app -- what am I missing?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, rest, gatsby

**EDIT:** Found a workable solution, but it involves editing some core files in the ACF to RESTAPI plugin, see here:

https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api/issues/141

Research:

[Update ACF fields inside layout via WP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596688/update-acf-fields-inside-layout-via-wp-api)

https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api-example/issues/1 (I tried all of the solutions in this Github link to no avail.)

I'm using ACF Pro version 6.1.4 and WP version 6.2, all the latest.

The subject line says it all, but here are some more details:

- I discovered early on that you need "fields" as the key for a POST/update request.
- I'm able to update other user fields, ie Wordpress core fields, just fine.
- I'm authenticating using Application Passwords, and that's been working fine.
- My user field is currently set to: *User Form is equal to All.*
- It's exposed to GraphQL and the RestAPI.
- Again, this is an ACF field assigned to Users. I'm able to update ACF fields assigned to other content types, eg posts and custom post types, just fine.
- This is a reactjs app, Gatsby, if it matters.

Example Javascript code below. Note that I'm able to update the email field with no trouble, but **I can't seem to update ACF fields assigned to users**. (And I need to lol.)

Thank you!

```
fetch("http://xxxx.xxx/wp-json/wp/v2/users/5", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ':' + application_password),
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 

        email: "testemail@gmail.com",
        fields: {
            test_user_field: '5555'
        }
           

})
})
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))

}
```

Comment: Naturally, as soon as I post this, I run across a forum post that seems to solve the problem. Here's the link, and I'll share more details above:

https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api/issues/141